# Laravel Large CSV import using maatwebsite Excel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, maatwebsite-excel

I have a CSV file with 30k rows. I have used [maatwebsite excel](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/) to import CSV in my PGSQL database.

The problem is every time it uploads 10k-12k data in the database, the page gives **HTTP ERROR 500**

##### Error

> ###### This page isn’t working
>
> localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
> HTTP ERROR 500

I have changed the following variables in `php.ini`

```
max_execution_time=0
max_input_time=3000
post_max_size=128M
```

I have tried the below code in  `ReportsImport`

```
class UserReport implements ToModel, WithCustomCsvSettings, WithChunkReading, WithHeadingRow
{
    public function model(array $row)
    {
          // dd($row);
          return new UserReport([
              'user'     => $row['username'],
              'amount'   => $row['amount']
          ]);
    }
    
    public function getCsvSettings(): array
    {
         return [
              'input_encoding' => 'UTF-8'
         ];
    }
    
    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
        return 1000;
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this `HTTP 500 error`?

- Error Log: `local.ERROR: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted`
- Version: Laravel Framework 7.26.1

Comment: What's in the error log?

Comment: @Thomas local.ERROR: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted

Comment: Did you add the `implements WithChunkReading`? What happens if you decrease the cunk size?

Comment: try using jobs to handle this task

Comment: @Thomas I have updated my code, shared full class what I have written. I have reduced chunk size 1000 to 200 only 800 increased !

Comment: Did you try decreasing the chunk size? If that doesn't help I would try adding [Batch inserts](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/chunk-reading.html#using-it-together-with-batch-inserts) next (in addition to the existing Chunk reading).

Comment: @Thomas After use Batch Insert It has worked !! Thank you so much ! Would you please add this as an answer ?

Comment: @NiloyRony done, glad it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the application is trying to hold too much data in memory. I see you're already using [Chunk reading](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/chunk-reading.html) but it appears not to be enough

To decrease the memory consumption when reading the table data, try decreasing your chunk size.

To decrease the memory consumption of the models, try adding [Batch inserts](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/batch-inserts.html) in addition to chunk reading .